# Passing arguments to a ruby script

Tags: ruby, daemons

I run a file like this:

```
ruby hello.rb world.csv data.csv
```

How would the start file look? I have this.

```
require 'daemons'

pwd  = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

wFile = "#{pwd}/world.csv"
dFile = "#{pwd}/data.csv" 

Daemons.run("hello.rb #{wFile} #{dFile}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create a file `hello_daemon.rb` like this:

```
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run("hello.rb")
```

And run it (you can use one of `start`, `restart` or `run`):

```
ruby hello_daemon.rb start -- world.csv data.csv
```

And `daemons` will run your `hello.rb` as

```
ruby hello.rb world.csv data.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Use global constant [ARGV](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html) (although there's not much to learn) to receive an array of strings with the parameters.
 So for your case:

```
require 'daemons'

files = []
ARGV.each do |arg|
  files << File.expand_path(arg)
end
```

This should give you absolute paths to every argument, so that you can open them from anywhere.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding me. In hello.rb I have it set to accept the arguments as ARGV[0] and ARGV[1] but it Daemons doesn't pass it correctly.

Comment: `ARGV[0]` is probably the name of the current file

Comment: Likely, he misunderstood your question.